# How to use JSON in OrientDB HTTP command request

Tags: orientdb

I'm using orientdb-community-2.2-alpha and I'm trying to use JSON payloads with the HTTP command API (as in calling `http://<host>:<port>/command/<database>/sql`) and I simply can't figure out how to do it. All I get is an `OCommandExecutorNotFoundException` saying `Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.<whatever JSON I tried here>` no matter what I try.

I'm not providing an example of what I've tried as I'm not trying to do any one specific thing; I would just like to see a working curl example of how to post a generic command request using a JSON payload.

I can use JSON with batch requests just fine, it's just the command API that I can't get to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Postman plugin

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful tool. However, I'm still not having any luck, even using the exact example query given in the  [API description](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html#command).

I'm still getting an error like  

    `2015-12-09 09:53:48:727 SEVER Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.{"command": "select from V where name = :name and city = :city","parameters": {"name": "Luca","city": "Rome"}}`